# Mounted directory is shrinking

Tags: mount, zsh

This is a bit strange. I have a ZSH mounted network directory in a Redhat VM and it appears to be shrinking:

```
[aramk@server-C production]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             8.7G  7.2G  1.1G  87% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
myserver:/mypath
                      3.0G  2.9G   74M  98% /mnt/mydir

[aramk@server-C www]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             8.7G  7.2G  1.1G  87% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
myserver:/mypath
                      2.9G  2.8G   74M  98% /mnt/mydir

[aramk@server-C confluence]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             8.7G  7.2G  1.1G  87% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
myserver:/mypath
                      2.5G  2.4G   74M  98% /mnt/mydir

[aramk@server-C ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             8.7G  7.2G  1.1G  87% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
myserver:/mypath
                      2.3G  2.3G  1.0M 100% /mnt/mydir
```

I was forced to use [this method](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/wiki/Disk_quota_exceeded,_unable_to_delete_files) to remove some files, but then I removed too much and it shrank again from 3GB to 2.4GB. The original drive was 10GB and shrank down to 6GB and then to 3GB as I removed unnecessary files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be process issue. The backup snapshots saved in a `.zhs` directory in the mounted directory were not appearing under the disk usage but were taking up space from the 10GB quota. I'll leave this answer here in case others have a similar issue, but it seems pretty isolated.